# How to handling error in decorate function?

Tags: javascript, function, design-patterns

I'm trying to decorate my function that has an error handling like this.

```js
// Target function 

async function update(){
  try{
   await someAsyncFunction()
  }
  catch(err){
   return Promise.reject(err)
  }
}

// Decorate function 

async function notify(fn){
 try{
  await fn()
  await publish()
 }
 catch(err){
  return err
 }
```

So, we can call the function like this

```js
notify(update)
```

But the problem comes when the publish method throwing an error, it should break the function of notifying. The goal of this method the notify should be logging error only and if the update method throwing an error, it should fail to publish.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do `return err` when you want to re-throw it. Don't let `update` recursively call itself. If `publish` is asynchronous, you will need to `await` it as well.

Comment: I just want to keep my update `function` should be same with the existing behaviour including the `return err`. 
I don't know what do you mean recursively, I just passing function of update to another function and called from that function.
Yeah, it should be await, I'll update the question. Thanks

Comment: But with `return err` it does *not* have the same behaviour as `update()`!

Comment: Edited : I recognise recursively call in my question, it should call another function in update method.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return`ing the error in your `notify` function, you should re`throw` it (you can't do both together). You may want to do some kind of logging before rethrowing it.

Also, about the `update` function, you can `throw` the error directly and it will automatically be wrapped as a promise rejection. And if all what will be in the `catch` block is just rethrowing the error (with no plan for additional handling), then I'd suggest removing the try-catch block altogether.